# Kubernetes Metrics unable to fetch pod/node metrics

Tags: kubernetes

I've installed metrics-server on kubernetes v1.11.2.

I'm running a bare-metal cluster using 3 nodes and 1 master

In the metrics-server log I have the following errors:

```
E0907 14:29:51.774592       1 manager.go:102] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:vps01: unable to 
fetch metrics from Kubelet vps01 (vps01): Get https://vps01:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup vps01 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scr
ape metrics from source kubelet_summary:vps04: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet vps04 (vps04): Get https://vps04:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup 
vps04 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:vps03: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet vps03 (vps03): 
Get https://vps03:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup vps03 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:vp
s02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet vps02 (vps02): Get https://vps02:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup vps02 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host]     
E0907 14:30:01.694794       1 reststorage.go:98] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod boxweb/boxweb-deployment-7756c49688-fz625: no metrics known for pod "bo
xweb/boxweb-deployment-7756c49688-fz625"                                                                                                                    
E0907 14:30:10.517886       1 reststorage.go:112] unable to fetch node metrics for node "vps01": no metrics known for node "vps01"
```

I also can't get any metrics using 
  kubectl top node vps01

Same for autoscale it is not working

```
  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from
 resource metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Answer (score 14):

I found the following solution:

Change the `metrics-server-deployment.yaml` file and add:

```
command:
    - /metrics-server 
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

Comment: where should I add the lines, there are 2 configuration and many keys... 
i'm using the metrics-server/deploy/1.8+

Comment: You should add in the path: spec/template/spec/containers.
Below the tag "image"

Comment: I think using insecure-tls in any environment (except dev-testing) shouldn't be a valid answer.

Comment: To make it work, I need to add another argument: --v=2

Comment: works for me like a magic

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have DNS issue from your `metrics-server` pod. You can connect to the pod:

```
kubectl exec -it metrics-server-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx -n kube-system sh
/ # ping vps01
```

If you can't ping you can't resolve your node.

core-dns or kube-dns use the `/etc/resolv.conf` on each on your nodes too, so I would check if you can resolve the nodes between each other. Say, can you ping `vps01` from `vps02` or `vps03`, etc.

Comment: I can't ping the node from the pod nor from another node. However I have a bunch of pods that are running well on the cluster. Any idea how I can fix the DNS?

Comment: I tried to nslookup kubernetes.default from a busybox container and it resolves. I tried to do it from the metrics pod but it does not resolve however the resolve.conf file is the same. I can't resolve vps01 from the busybox either

Comment: Fix the `/etc/resolv.conf` on each one of their nodes.  They should be able to resolve to each other, it all depends on what domain you want your servers to be in and the DNS server that they are using.   It should have a `domain <your-domain>` entry and also a `nameserver <dns server>` entry

Comment: You mean fixing the DNS on the host itself ? I have this : 
nameserver 127.0.0.53                                                                                                                                                                   
search openstacklocal
On all the hosts

Comment: Yes. Fix it on the nodes themselves. Can you resolve `vps01.openstacklocal`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I resolved by adding hostname in `/etc/hosts` on every node.

For collecting metric data (CPU/memory usage) metric-server try to access the nodes. However, the metric-server cannot resolve the hostname(`vps01`, `vps02`, `vps03`, and `vps04`) because the ones are not registered in DNS. As you mentioned, you cannot register the hostnames in DNS.

So, you must add the hostnames to `/etc/hosts` on the node where the metrics-server POD is running.

The autoscaler does not work since the metric-server is not working and there is no metric data.

Answer (score 0):

Patch `metrics-server` deployment:

```
$ kubectl patch -n kube-system deployment metrics-server --type=json \
  -p '[{"op":"add","path":"/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/-","value":"--kubelet-insecure-tls"}]'
```