# Kubernetes: kubectl top nodes/pods not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubelet, kubernetes-metrics

When I do `kubectl top pods/nodes` I am getting the following error:

> metrics not available yet

When I check the logs I am getting

```
$ kubectl logs metrics-server-7df4c4484d-h75wr -n kube-system -c metrics-server

I1008 12:02:55.159069       1 serving.go:273] Generated self-signed cert(apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.crt, apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.key)
[restful] 2018/10/08 12:02:56 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://:443/swaggerapi
[restful] 2018/10/08 12:02:56 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] https://:443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
I1008 12:02:56.358063       1 serve.go:96] Serving securely on [::]:443
E1008 12:03:04.225519       1 reststorage.go:101] unable to fetch node metrics for node "hpa-test": no metrics known for node "hpa-test"
E1008 12:03:07.619489       1 reststorage.go:101] unable to fetch node metrics for node "hpa-test": no metrics known for node "hpa-test"
```

Also, I am able to ping to hpa-test node from:

```
$ kubectl exec -it  metrics-server-7df4c4484d-h75wr -n kube-system sh
```

Also, I have tried looking for solution everywhere but nothing fixed the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes Metrics unable to fetch pod/node metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224829/kubernetes-metrics-unable-to-fetch-pod-node-metrics)

Comment: No its not a duplicate i am able to ping to nodes from metrics-server container

Answer (score 15):

There are two ways to fix this problem:

1) using **heapster** :
installing heapster will allow *'kubectl top nodes'* to work out of the box. However heapster has been deprecated, so you probably should switch to metrics-server.

2) using **metrics-server** :
unfortunately it may not work out of the box when installing metrics-server...
in case it doesn't, you need to update the end of the metrics-server-deployment.yaml (1.8+) file you used for installation and **add a command section** with the right parameters as follow:

```
containers:
- name: metrics-server
  image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.1
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  volumeMounts:
  - name: tmp-dir
    mountPath: /tmp

  command:
      - /metrics-server
      - --kubelet-insecure-tls
      - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

then simply apply the changes:

> kubectl apply -f metrics-server-deployment.yaml

you should then be able to get results with

> kubectl top nodes

and

> kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes"

Answer (score 4):

Need add flags for metrics-sever:

```
--kubelet-insecure-tls=true
--kubelet-port={YOU_KUBELET_PORT}
--kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
--v=5
--logtostderr
```

Comment: I am new to k8s can u please tell where should i add those flags in my yaml

Comment: @Mallikarjun Br  Thats flags for Kubelet, you may found it here `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` and add variable

Comment: How do i restart kubelet after adding them does it restart automatically?

Comment: This no flag for kubelet. This flag for metrics-server

Comment: @DenisA. Where should i add them in metrics-server-deployment.yaml can u help me

Comment: Yes, you need edit deploy (metrics-server in namespace kube-system)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the deployment of metrics-server and add the following to arguments to its container.

```
--kubelet-insecure-tls
--kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

For example,

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: metrics-server
  ...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
      - name: metrics-server
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.6
        args:
          - --kubelet-insecure-tls
          - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If metrics are enabled but not running

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep metrics-server
```

If no pods are returned, you can deploy the latest version of the Metrics Server by running the following command:

```
wget https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

Edit the `components.yaml` content. Add `- --kubelet-insecure-tls`, `- /metrics-server`, `imagePullPolicy: Always` under `Deployment::spec::template::spec::containers::args`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        - /metrics-server
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

```
kubectl apply -f components.yaml
minikube stop
minikube start
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to comment on is that the **--kubelet-insecure-tls** is in fact, insecure and shouldn't be used, especially since a good answer is available in the documentation. This is an older article but I wanted to make sure a good answer is provided for others who are searching.

Following the below Kubernetes doc/link will solve the problem for you. It is listed under the kubeadm docs though. I do use **kubeadm** to manage my clusters so I know this works. I can't speak to other implementations.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#kubelet-serving-certs

Answer (score -1):

These issue  arises because you don't have metric server enabled in your cluster

**The top command will only be running if the metric server installed on your cluser**

Download metric server in Kubernetes API from the git

**Step:1**    `git clone  https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server.git`

**Step:2**    `cd metrics-server/`

**Step:3** Deploy

Kubernetes 1.7
`kubectl create -f deploy/1.7/`

Kubernetes 1.8

```
kubectl create -f deploy/1.8+/
```

**Setp :4**  Check status of metric server pod

```
 kubectl get po -n kube-system |grep metrics
```

**Step5:**
Now your top command will be running

```
kubectl top pod --all-namespaces
```