# Metric server unable to fetch monitoring data from the node where his pod is placed

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

I am trying to figure out why Metric server isn't collecting stats from the node where it is deployed (r2s13). There are 3 nodes in my cluster (1 master and 2 workers).

- **metric server version:** 0.3.1
- **kubernetes version:** 1.12 (installed with kubeadm)
- **CNI plugin:** weave net

**`kubectl top node` output:**

```
NAME CPU(cores) CPU% MEMORY(bytes) MEMORY%

r2s12 344m 4% 3079Mi 12%

r2s14 67m 0% 1695Mi 21%

r2s13
```

In metric server log, I have the below line repeated (just for the node where the metric server is deployed `r2s13`):

```
E1023 15:28:14.643011 1 manager.go:102] unable to fully collect metrics: unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:r2s13: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet r2s13 (10.199.183.218): Get https://10.199.183.218:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp 10.199.183.218:10250: i/o timeout
```

I can't ping from the pod to the node where it is deployed.

I have added below config in metric server:

```
    command:
    - /metrics-server
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

Comment: Have you tried to fix /etc/resolv.conf as @Rico suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230952/9929015 ?

Comment: Yes the resolve.conf on each node contains all the nodes. and the ping between the nodes is OK; while I can't ping from inside the metric pod to the IP of its hosting node.

Comment: @Hanna do you solved the problem ? I have a similar problem now and any news about this will help me.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here (and also using the same extra arguments). Has anyone already found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the firewall wouldn't allow incoming traffic from Weave.

Executing the following fixed the problem

```
ufw allow in on weave
ufw reload
```