# HPA with windows worker nodes - EKS 1.11

Tags: windows, kubernetes, containers

HPA doesn't work and keeps showing /10% for targets.

Metrics-server is installed and registers fine

```
PS C:\k> kubectl get apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io -o yaml

status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2019-07-31T08:20:04Z
    message: all checks passed
    reason: Passed
    status: "True"
    type: Available
```

checking the logs for the metrics-server pod

```
$ kubectl logs metrics-server-686978657d-8rvzs -n kube-system

kubectl
E0731 20:30:09.062734       1 manager.go:102] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.internal: [unable t
o get CPU for node "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.internal": missing cpu usage metric, unable to get CPU for container "windows-server-iis" in pod default/windows-server-iis-846f465947-n9t
tg on node "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.internal": missing cpu usage metric], unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.internal: [un
able to get CPU for node "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.internal": missing cpu usage metric, unable to get CPU for container "mymicroservice-eks" in pod default/mymicroservice-eks-5f47bc8
9bb-4nmkc on node "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.internal": missing cpu usage metric], unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.inte
rnal: [unable to get CPU for node "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.internal": missing cpu usage metric, unable to get CPU for container "mymicroservice-eks" in pod default/mymicroservice-e
ks-5f47bc89bb-dv9gx on node "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.internal": missing cpu usage metric, unable to get CPU for container "windows-iis" in pod default/windows-iis-64ddbbd57-929hv o
n node "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west.computer.internal": missing cpu usage metric]]
E0731 20:30:17.560396       1 reststorage.go:98] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod default/windows-iis-64ddbbd57-929hv: no metrics known for pod "default/windows-iis-64ddbbd57-929hv"
E0731 20:30:47.565251       1 reststorage.go:98] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod default/windows-iis-64ddbbd57-929hv: no metrics known for pod "default/windows-iis-64ddbbd57-929hv"
```

Deployment YAML

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: windows-server-iis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: windows-server-iis
      tier: backend
      track: stable
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: windows-server-iis
        tier: backend
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: windows-server-iis
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809 
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
        - powershell.exe
        - -command
        - "Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/servicemonitor/2.0.1.6/ServiceMonitor.exe ' -OutFile 'C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe'; echo '<html><body><br/><br/><marquee><H1>Hello EKS!!!<H1><marquee></body><html>' > C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\default.html; C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe 'w3svc'; "
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os:  windows
```

Details of the hpa that I have configured are provided below

```
PS C:\k> kubectl get hpa
NAME          REFERENCE                TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
windows-iis   Deployment/windows-server-iis   <unknown>/10%   1         10        1          16m
```

What am I missing, is HPA not supported for windows containers ?

Comment: Provide more details, your HPA, Deployment YAMLs.

Comment: edited the question to include hpa & deployment yaml

Answer (score 0):

Error you have provided: no metrics known for pod "default/windows-iis-64ddbbd57-929hv means that metrics-server pod did not received any updated. Due to lack of any CPU usage or wrong `spec.scaleTargetRef:` declaration. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) you can find Kubernetes example. Without `kubectl describe hpa  is hard to say.

During searching solution for this I found that many people on EKS have similar problem. For example on [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/237) or [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224829/kubernetes-metrics-unable-to-fetch-pod-node-metrics).
Please try to add this to your deployment.

```
command:
    - /metrics-server 
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

However you mentioned that you are using `Windows Containers`. According to [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/intro-windows-in-kubernetes/) Kubernetes is supporting HPA on Windows Containers since version 1.15. If you are using pervious version HPA will not work.

Hope it helps.